# How to search for text on page then continue script from that point

Tags: imacros

My example script clicks the first "rate" button it finds on a page, yet I want it to find text and then click the next "rate" button on a page.

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Users\admin\Documents\iMacros\Downloads\extract.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
SEARCH SOURCE=TXT:"my favorite energy drink" 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Rating:<SP>Good<SP>Answer
WAIT SECONDS=2
```

The search line seems to work, yet the tag line jumps the script back to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Rating:<SP>Good<SP>Answer
```

With this:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Rating:<SP>Good<SP>Answer
```

Comment: That jumps to 2ed link each time, I'm hoping for it to be smarter and use the search to find the right link no mater if it's in pos 1, 2, 3 etc.    Thanks though.

Comment: Then use better text to describe what to search.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Rating:<SP>Good<SP>Answer
```

With this:

```
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:*<SP>Rating:<SP>Good<SP>Answer
```

The 'R' in the position refers to "Relative", so no matter where it first finds what you are searching for it will look for the link/txt/etc in 1 position directly after what it found.  You can also have it work in reverse ex. POS=R-1